# How to load 32 bit dll on 64 bit matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to load a 32-bit library on 64-bit Matlab but this error appears:

```
 Error using loaddefinedlibrary

D:\Code\Thinkgear.dll is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I was wondering if there is any way to solve this issue please?

Comment: Is the DLL a COM component?

Comment: Yes, it is used for connecting the neurosky device via bluetooth.

Comment: If it has the appropriate metadata for marshaling, you might be able to load it out-of-process (a 32-bit COM surrogate will load the DLL, and MATLAB will access it remotely via a marshaling stub)

Comment: So how can I load it please?

Comment: Something like this: http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/   It's only for COM components though, loaded into MATLAB via http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/actxserver.html

Comment: @BenVoigt worth an answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt Can you show me an example on my code? as I am new in the com field.

Comment: I don't know what your ProgID is, or have any way to test it.

Comment: I am mainly trying to run that code https://www.pantechsolutions.net/matlab-code-to-read-meditation-using-mindwave-mobile